# Would the volume of water usage change if we increase water pressure using a booster pump? Not changing pipe diameter, length or viscosity

Tags: flow-control

This is for a clean up crew, I am wondering if we do not change our hose size, nozzle size on the sprayer.  The pressure out of the water heater would be 65psi and they want to add a booster pump to go up to 90 psi.  Would they use more water in the same amount of time with the increased pressure?  I am trying to see how to calculate to see if I need a bigger water heater/storage tank.

Comment: Would the lower temperature make a difference in the job ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use approximately 1.3 times more water.

To calculate the volume you need to enter the pipe dimensions, roughness, static head, and friction head in a, readily available, online app.

Here is the link to one such online headloss calculator app.

[head loss app](https://www.pumpfundamentals.com/php_pages/pump/head-5.php?sh=60&dia=2&le=50&info_true=)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't change the setup but pressure, you can get your answer by direct comparison on flow rates interpolated through data in the table below. link to the site https://hy-techroofdrains.com/water-flow-through-a-pipe/

[image: enter image description]